# How to extend the pseudo element placed absolutely until the page content gets the best?

Tags: css, css-position

I wrote such a code. I write this code so that `.vertical_catch p: after` is from the position where the element is absolutely placed to the bottom where the page content exists

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

.vertical_catch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58%;
  left: 4%;
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical_catch p {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical_catch p:after {
  z-index: 50;
  margin: 1em 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;  /* I want to get 100% height of page content */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.7px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
}

.minibox {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 150px;
  background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
  margin: 40px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="hero"></div>

  <div class="vertical_catch">
    <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <section class="minibox">
      <h1>heading1</h1>
      <section class="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <section class="minibox">
      <h1>heading2</h1>
      <section class="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </p>
      </section>
    </section>

  </div>

</body>
```

However, height: 100% only worked up to 100vh, and could not extend the border to the bottom of the content.

According to the developer tool verification,in html and body, the height includes all page content, but the element of absolute arrangement could not obtain the height. height: 100% only worked up to 100vh.

How can I extend the border?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `100%` height for `::after` element; it will take up the full height of the `p`, its main element. Consider editing as below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

.vertical_catch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 4%;
  height: 90%;
}

.vertical_catch p {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical_catch p:after {
      z-index: 50;
margin: 1em 0;
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
height: 80%; 
display: inline-block;
width: 1.7px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background-color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
}

.minibox {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 150px;
  background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
  margin: 40px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="hero"></div>

  <div class="vertical_catch">
    <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <section class="minibox">
      <h1>heading1</h1>
      <section class="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <section class="minibox">
      <h1>heading2</h1>
      <section class="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </p>
      </section>
    </section>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The answer code will be at the bottom of the page, can I fill it in?

 I tried to set the height of :: after element to 100%, but the border got out from the bottom of the page. I applied `overflow: hidden` as a workaround, but this did not work.

Comment: the height of the ::pseudo element depends on the element it is being attached to, so it will depend on the `.vertical_catch` div, and apparently the height `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

.vertical_catch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 4%;
  height: 90%;
}

.vertical_catch p {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  height: 100%;
}

.vertical_catch p:after {
z-index: 50;
margin: 1em 0;
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
height: calc(100% - 388px);
display: inline-block;
width: 1.7px;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background-color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
}

.minibox {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 150px;
  background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
  margin: 40px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="hero"></div>

  <div class="vertical_catch">
    <p>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <section class="minibox">
      <h1>heading1</h1>
      <section class="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </p>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <section class="minibox">
      <h1>heading2</h1>
      <section class="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        </p>
      </section>
    </section>

  </div>

</body>
```